# C++ std::accumulate doesn't give the expected sum

Tags: c++

```
double numbers[ ] = { 1, 0.5 ,0.333333 ,0.25 ,0.2, 0.166667, 0.142857, 0.125,
                       0.111111, 0.1 } ;
std::vector<double> doublenumbers ( numbers , numbers + 10 ) ;
std::cout << std::accumulate ( doublenumbers.begin( ) , doublenumbers.end( ) , 0 ) ;
```

This produces 1, which is evidently wrong. Any explanations?

Comment: +1, this is an important gotcha that's bitten me several times.

Comment: also, the vector is not necessary; you can use pointers as iterators: `std::accumulate ( numbers, numbers + sizeof numbers / sizeof *numbers, 0.0);`. [In real code you'd probably have a constant or variable `num_numbers` rather than `sizeof numbers / sizeof *numbers`]

Comment: See my answer for an easy way to prevent this headache in the future.

Answer (score 73):

You should write the following:

```
std::cout << 
 std::accumulate ( doublenumbers.begin( ) , doublenumbers.end( ) , 0.0 ) ;
```

Because the type of 0 is `int`.

When `std::accumulate` is instantiated with the type of the third argument is `int`, then it would convert the right hand side of the sum. e.g.:

```
   result += *iter;
// int    += double
```

This would force a conversion of `double` to `int`, instead of what you were thinking of which is the opposite.

Comment: What is amusing is that even using `0.0` there could still be some discrepancies (for large sums) because of the approximate representation of floating numbers. `std::vector<float> v(1000, 1000.1f); std::cout << std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0.0f);` yields `1.00011e+06` because float only has 5/6 digits worth of precision on my machine.

Comment: I just had to same problem. Now I just wonder, how one is supposed to know this from the documentation (e.g. http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate)? This is a serious question and not a complaint. I really would like to get more used to C++.

Comment: @MatthieuM. This isn't a particular issue with `std::accumulate`, right?

Comment: @Isaac: It's an issue common to all floating points summations.

Answer (score 9):

You're calling `accumulate` with `0` as the `init` argument, so it'll accumulate using integer maths.  Use `0.0` instead.

Answer (score 9):

`std::accumulate` will start to sum the type that is passed as 3rd argument, if you pass an integer, the return type will be `int`. And in this case implicitly converted to a `double`.
**In C++11 and C++14**, if you want to prevent narrowing conversion, you could create an object using *direct-list-initialization*:

```
double sum { std::accumulate(doublenumbers.begin(), doublenumbers.end(), 0) };
```

The compiler will then give you a warning saying that you are trying to convert from int to double and also at which line. This will save you debugging time. And you can easily fix it so that it becomes correct:

```
double sum { std::accumulate(doublenumbers.begin(), doublenumbers.end(), 0.0) };
```

Comment: For flout output we can use 0.0f.

Comment: Great answer: I was stuck until I read this. I casted the third argument; in my case, to a ``long long``, like so. ``long long s = std::accumulate(arr.begin(), arr.end(), static_cast<long long>(0));``

Answer (score 6):

```
std::accumulate ( doublenumbers.begin( ) , doublenumbers.end( ) , .0 ) ;
```

or

```
std::accumulate ( doublenumbers.begin( ) , doublenumbers.end( ) , (double) 0 ) ;
```

The type of the "accumulator" variable is the type of the last argument of `std::accumulate`. You supplied `0` as an argument - an `int` literal - which means that the accumulator will have type `int`. The "accumulation" is done in an `int` accumulator (i.e. rounded to `int` after each individual summation) and produces `int` result. In this case it is, apparently, `1`.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::accumulate<double> (doublenumbers.begin(), doublenumbers.end(), 0); // also works
```

Comment: My suspicion is that some template parameters got gobbled.  Enclose your code in ticks (`) to keep that from happening.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This would be a better answer if you had mentioned *why* that works, and also if you had drawn attention to what exactly you changed. It's the difference between giving a man a fish and teaching him to fish.

Comment: Ahh, if that is what you intended, then I'm not certain that will work.  `std::accumulate` takes two template parameters in this case.  One to define the iterator type, and one to define the return type.  If you only provide one, it will match to the first parameter, and still guess the second.

Comment: Specifying the template arguments of course works but the first type is the iterator type so it's not pretty: std::accumulate<std::vector<double>::iterator, double>(doublenumbers.begin(), doublenumbers.end(), 0);

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add (maybe) another useful answer.

For those who got wrong sum on `unsigned long long int` or `long long int`, you need to cast the init value to that particular type.

```
std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), (long long int) 0) // or (unsigned long long int)
```

or you can automatically cast based on the vector type:

```
std::accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), decltype(vec)::value_type(0))
```