# writing a function sumVector : not returning a value

Tags: c++, function, vector

I am practicing with functions on the vector class. i have written a function 'sumVector' to add up all elements of vector 'ages', but it is not returning the total
i am copying my code block; i know the STL provides a sum function but this is for my own practice. i would appreciate if someone would point out what i am doing wrong

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <fstream>
    #include <sstream>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iterator>
    #include <algorithm>
    using namespace std;
    template<typename T>
    int sumVector(const vector<T> &integers2)
    {
         typename vector<T>::const_iterator constIterator;
         //display vector elements using constIterator
         for 

         (constIterator=integers2.begin();                                             
         constIterator!=integers2.end();++constIterator);
         int sum=0;
         sum+=*constIterator;
         return sum;
         cout<<sum;
    }




    int main ()
    {
    vector<int> ages;
    vector<float>var;
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open("data.txt");
    if(!inFile)
    {
        cout<<"didn't work";
        cin.get();
        exit (1);
    }

    string line;
    getline(inFile, line);
    istringstream in(line);
    copy(std::istream_iterator<int>(in),
      std::istream_iterator<int>(),
      std::back_inserter(ages));
    cout<<ages.at(2)<<endl;
    getline(inFile, line);
    istringstream gin(line);
    copy(istream_iterator<float>(gin),
                                     istream_iterator<float>(),
                                     back_inserter(var));
    cout<<var.at(0)<<endl;
    cout<<"whats the sum";
    sumVector (ages);

    cin.get();

    inFile.close();
    cin.get();

    }
```

Comment: Really ill-formatted code, debug printing, `cout` after `return`?

Comment: The standard library function [accumulate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604478/c-stdaccumulate-doesnt-give-the-expected-sum) does this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `for` loop is incorrect and the `cout << sum` occurs after the `return` from `sumVector()`. The return type (and type of `sum`) should also be `T` otherwise `sumVector()` is restricted to `vector`s of elements of `int` (or types convertible to `int`s).

Something like the following I think is what your looking for:

```
template<typename T>
T sumVector(const vector<T> &integers2)
{
    typename vector<T>::const_iterator constIterator;
    T sum=0;
    //display vector elements using constIterator
    for (constIterator=integers2.begin();
         constIterator!=integers2.end();
         ++constIterator)
    {
        sum+=*constIterator;
    }

    cout<<sum;
    return sum;
}
```

Consider not printing the value of `sum` within `sumVector()` as (IMO) this is clearer:

```
cout << "whats the sum: " << sumVector(ages);
```

It may also be required to store the result of `sumVector()` in a variable and not write anything to standard output at the point the sum is calculated.

Answer (score 2):

The ";" after the for is wrong - the way you write it, the semicolon would be the body of the for loop.

I didn't touch your naming (e.g. *integers2* is a little irriating).

```
template<typename T>
int sumVector(const vector<T> &integers2)
{
     int sum=0;
     typename vector<T>::const_iterator constIterator;
     //display vector elements using constIterator
     for (constIterator=integers2.begin();constIterator!=integers2.end();++constIterator) {

         sum+=*constIterator;
     }
     cout<<sum;
     return sum;
}
```

I also reordered

- the **print** and the **return** of the sum, because the return end's the execution of the function.
- the initialization of **i=0** also must be done, before the loop.