# std::accumulate not acting as expected

Tags: c++, stl

I am getting an unexpected result using std::accumulate with test code. I am trying to add up a large vector of doubles but for some reason the value is overflowing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>

using namespace std;

double sum(double x, double y)
{
    // slows things down but shows the problem:
    //cout << x << " + " << y << endl;
    return (x+y);
}

double mean(const vector<double> & vec)
{
    double result = 0.0;

    // works:
    //vector<double>::const_iterator it;
    //for (it = vec.begin(); it != vec.end(); ++it){
    //      result += (*it);
    //}

    // broken:
    result = accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0, sum);

    result /= vec.size();

    return result;
}


int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{

    const unsigned int num_pts = 100000;

    vector<double> vec(num_pts, 0.0);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < num_pts; ++i){
        vec[i] = (double)i;
    }

    cout << "mean = " << mean(vec) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Partial output from the cout inside the sum:

> 2.14739e+09 + 65535 
>   **2.14745e+09 + 65536** 
>   **-2.14748e+09 + 65537** 
>   -2.14742e+09 + 65538 
>   -2.14735e+09 + 65539

Correct output (iterating):

> mean = 49999.5

Incorrect output (using accumulate):

> mean = 7049.5

I am probably making a tired mistake?  I have used accumulate successfully before...

Thanks

Comment: `stl::accumulate`? `std::algorithm`? Yeah, you are tired.

Comment: It happened to overflow exactly on n = 65536 because SUM(0..n) = (n)(n+1)/2.  Isn't math great

Comment: You might want to use [Kahan Summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kahan_summation_algorithm). See my answer to [sum of small double numbers c++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10330002/sum-of-small-double-numbers-c).

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ std::accumulate doesn't give the expected sum](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604478/c-stdaccumulate-doesnt-give-the-expected-sum)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to pass a `double` to `accumulate`:

```
result = accumulate(vec.begin(), vec.end(), 0.0, sum);
                                            ^^^
```

otherwise the accumulation is performed using `int`, and then converting the result to a double.

Comment: One minute and thirty seconds.  It amazes me how fast you guys notice things like this. +1

Comment: @Wug we might have made the same mistake before :)

Comment: @Wug: This is a standard gotcha with `std::accumulate`. Half the people probably guessed the answer before the page was even loaded, just from the title.