# warning using std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);

Tags: c++

Why do I get a warning `C4244  '=': conversion from '__int64' to '_Ty', possible loss of data`? Also, `auto` instead of `LONGLONG` produces this warning.

```cpp
std::vector<LONGLONG>& v = m_vecEstimatedTime;
LONGLONG nEstimatedTimeTotal = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);  //  warning C4244  '=': conversion from '__int64' to '_Ty'
```

Comment: What's `LONGLONG`? Please give a [mcve]

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604478/c-stdaccumulate-doesnt-give-the-expected-sum

Comment: A perhaps surprising feature of `accumulate` is that the result type is determined by the type of the initial value, not by the type of the elements. The reason for this is that it's more common than you think to want to accumulate a result of a type entirely different from the element type.

Answer (score 4):

The return type, and the summary value's type of [`std::accumulate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate) is determined by the initial value being passed. For `0` it'll be `int`.

If the type is supposed to be `LONGLONG`, you can specify the initial value as:

```
LONGLONG nEstimatedTimeTotal = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), static_cast<LONGLONG>(0));
```

Comment: It's not just the return type; it's also the type of the internal variable that accumulates values.

Comment: Assuming the `LONGLONG` typedef corresponds to `long long`, you can also use the shorthand `0LL`.

Comment: @0x5453 that is very elegant. I will use your solution.

Comment: @0x5453 -- **assuming** that the `LONGLONG` corresponds to `long long`, there is no reason for the code to use `LONGLONG`. If you hardcode the type with `0LL` you defeat the purpose of that type alias.

Answer (score 2):

`std::accumulate` adds up values in the range. Essentially, it looks like this:

```
template <class Iter, class Accum>
Accum accumulate(Iter first, Iter last, Accum x) {
    while (first != last)
        x += *first++;
    return x;
}
```

The problem that the compiler is warning you about is that in `accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0)` that internal sum is adding `LONGLONG` values to an `int` value; that's where the possible loss of precision occurs. `auto` doesn't remove that warning, because it's not just `nEstimblahblah` that's the culprit; the internal type also loses precision.

To fix it, in this case the third argument should have the same type as the things being added. The obvious way of doing that is with explicit types:

```
LONGLONG total = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), static_cast<LONGLONG>(0));
```

The drawback with this approach is that everything is hardcoded; if you want to change the type of the elements of the vector you have to change it in three places. You could use a typedef for the element type:

```
typedef LONGLONG elem_t;
std::vector<elem_t>& v = whatever;
elem_t total = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), static_cast<elem_t>(0));
```

Or, for even more flexible code, typedef the whole thing:

```
typedef std::vector<LONGLONG> ctr_t;
typedef typename ctr_t::value_type elem_t;
ctr_t& v = whatever;
elem_t total = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), static_cast<elem_t>(0));
```

With that version you can change the element type without changing the rest of the code, and you can change the container type without changing the rest of the code. On the other hand, this version is more verbose, and perhaps too flexible.

Comment: good explanation, @0x5454 has an even simpler solution with LL.

Comment: @TomTom -- the whole point of `LONGLONG` is that it might **not** be `long long`. Granted, that's unlikely, since `long long` became part of standard C with C99, but with a compiler that doesn't support `long long`, `LONGLONG` will be a valid type, while `long long` and the suffix `LL` (with all its capitalization variants) won't be. If you're assuming that `long long` will always be there, then get rid of `LONGLONG` and use `long long`.

Comment: Assuming `LONGLONG` is a integer type that has a similar interface as the default integers, I would probably do `auto total = std::accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), elem_t{});`

Comment: @Ranoiaetep -- sure, that works. I've never been a fan of `auto`.

Comment: @PeteBecker Sorry if it was misleading, the `auto` wasn't necessarily my point, I was trying to point out to initialize the integer directly with `elem_t{}`, instead of using a cast

Comment: @Ranoiaetep -- sure, that works. I've never been a fan of uniform initialization syntax. <g>